# Как вывести булевы множества в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, множества, set

Мне нужно вывести булевы множества вот такого множества:

```
set1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

На всякий случай:

Булевы множества в дискретной математике - это множество всех подмножеств данного множества.

Так, для множества `set2 = {1, 2, 3}`, булево множество будет таким:

```
set2_bool = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {}}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: булеан в русском языке - это "булево" (множество).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Применим функцию [`powerset()`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#combinatorics) из модуля [`more_itertools`](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/):

```
from more_itertools import powerset                         # pip install more-itertools

set2_bool = {frozenset(tuple_) for tuple_ in powerset(set2)}
```

---

Результат (в переменной `set2_bool`) для множества `set2 = {1, 2, 3}`:

> ```
> {frozenset(),
>  frozenset({2}),
>  frozenset({2, 3}),
>  frozenset({1}),
>  frozenset({1, 2}),
>  frozenset({3}),
>  frozenset({1, 3}),
>  frozenset({1, 2, 3})}
> ```

---

*Замечание:*

Вы бы, наверно, хотели лучше всего получить **красивый** результат в виде

```
{set(), {1}, ..., {10}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, ..., {1, 2, 3}, ..., {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 10}}
```

Но это *невозможно по определению*.

**В Питоне множество не может заключать в себе множества.**
(Говоря о *регулярных* множествах, т.е. о типе `set`.)

Вы можете легко проверить, что это сделать нельзя:
Попробуйте в Питоне написать например `{{1, 2}}`, и вы получите ошибку

> ```
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
> ```

К счастию, в Питоне находится тоже тип `frozenset` («замёрзшее» множество).

---

*Объяснение:*

Сначала напомним, что решением было

```
from more_itertools import powerset                         # pip install more-itertools

set2_bool = {frozenset(tuple_) for tuple_ in powerset(set2)}
```

и теперь его объясним:

1. Используем функцию [`powerset()`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#combinatorics) из модуля [`more_itertools`](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/).

   Эта функция возвращает *генератор,* который генерирует все подмножества, но к сожалению не в виде множеств, а *кортежей.*
2. Генератором множества

   ```
   {frozenset(tuple_) for tuple_ in powerset(set2)}
   ```

   выбираем постепенно каждую из этих кортежей (`tuple_`) и конвертируем ее в «замёрзшее» множество (`frozenset`), получая в итоге их множество.

Answer (score 3):

Для этого можно воспользоваться модулем `itertools` и его встроенными функциями `chain` и `combinations`:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations


def powerset(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s) + 1))

print(list(powerset({1, 2, 3})))  # -> [(), (1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Либо вот так:

```
print(list(map(set, powerset({1, 2, 3}))))  # -> [set(), {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}]
```

[Оригинал вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482308/how-to-get-all-subsets-of-a-set-powerset)